# Show that $G/H\cong\mathbb{R}^*$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-isomorphism, infinite-groups

> Let $G:=
> \bigg\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> a & b  \\
> 0 & a  \\
> \end{array} \right)\Bigg| a,b \in \mathbb{R},a\ne 0\bigg\}$.  Let $H:=
> \bigg\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & b  \\
> 0 & 1  \\
> \end{array} \right) \Bigg| b \in \mathbb{R}\bigg\}$.
>   I know that $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$.  I need to prove that $G/H\cong\mathbb{R}^*$.

**My attempt:**

$$G/H=\{gH\mid g\in G\}$$

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
0 & a  \\
\end{array} \right)
$$
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & b  \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & ab+b  \\
0 & a
\end{array} \right)
$$

And there are $\infty$  solutions from the form :$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & ab  \\
0 & a
\end{array} \right)
$.

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & ab  \\
0 & a
\end{array} \right)\end{vmatrix}=\mathfrak{c}=|\mathbb{R}^*|
$$

$$\Rightarrow G/N\cong \mathbb{R}^*$$

Is it correct? is there another way to solve this?

Comment: No it is not correct. Knowing that to groups have the same cardinality is not enough to prove that they are isomorphic (for example $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^*,\times)$ have the same cardinality, yet they are not isomorphic. By the way, there is a mistake in your matrix multiplication.

Comment: edited the matix multiplication

Comment: Is $R^*$ the group of real numbers under multiplication?

Comment: yes, multiplication without zero

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't quite understand your solution, but here is another way to do it:

You can get the isomorphism from the First Isomorphism Theorem. For example, consider the map
$$
\phi: G \to \mathbb{R}^\times
$$
given by 
$$
\phi\pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & a} = a.
$$
You have to show that this map

1. is a homomorphism,
2. is surjective,
3. has $H$ as kernel.

Then the First Isomorhpism Theorem will tell you that $G / H \simeq \mathbb{R}^\times$.

---

If you don't know the First Isomorphism Theorem, you can define the map
$$
\psi: G/H \to \mathbb{R}^\times
$$
by
$$
\psi \pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & a}H = a
$$
and show that this map is

1. well defined,
2. a homomorphism,
   3, surjective,
3. injective.

(Is you do this, then you pretty much prove the First Isomorphism Theorem in this special case.)

Answer (score 3):

How about considering the map $\varphi:G\to\mathbb{R}^*$ sending $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\mapsto a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}^*$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$?  Why is it a group homomorphism?  What are the kernel and the image of $\varphi$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "backwards" proof:

Suppose $A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{bmatrix},A' = \begin{bmatrix}a'&b'\\0&a'\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $AH = A'H \iff a = a'$, since $AA'^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}a/a'&(-ab')/a'^2+b/a'\\0&a/a'\end{bmatrix}$

(Note how we use the fact that $a' \neq 0$).

Note as well that $AH = (aI)H$.

Thus $a \mapsto (aI)H$ is the desired isomorphism.